# How to only display the max count result for each

Tags: sql

I have vusers with nb on longon(totalcount) on each vcomputers displayed.

I would like to display only the vcomputer with the max totalcount for each vuser

This way, only the vcomputer with the max logon will be displayed

### Thanks

```
SELECT DISTINCT [vUser]       
,[vcomputer]      
,vFullName        
,COUNT(vUser) over ( partition by vcomputer, vuser )as totalCount     

FROM [PRD_TechnoWin].[dbo].[v_Logonstats_PFB]  
Where vComputer Not Like '%-VX%'   
And vComputer Not Like '%-V%'   
And v_Logonstats_PFB.vComputer Not Like '%XDAS%'   
And v_Logonstats_PFB.vComputer Not Like '%XDDS%' 
And v_Logonstats_PFB.vComputer Not Like 'VM%'  
And v_Logonstats_PFB.vComputer Not Like '%TEST%'   
And v_Logonstats_PFB.vComputer Not Like '%FOR%'   
And v_Logonstats_PFB.vComputer Not Like '%GPW%%'   
And v_Logonstats_PFB.vComputer Not Like '%PW%' 
And v_Logonstats_PFB.vComputer Not Like '%DW1%'
And v_Logonstats_PFB.vComputer Not Like '%GRP-PFB-32BIT%'  
And vDateTimeLogon > GETDATE()-45  

GROUP BY  vComputer,  vUser,  vFullName,  vDateTimeLogon  
order by vUser, totalcount desc
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoH8l.jpg)

Comment: The simplest: wrap it into another query with a `group by` and `max()`.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server:

Using [**`top with ties`**](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/use-top-filter-with-ties-option) with [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

```
select top 1 with ties
    [vUser]
  , [vcomputer]
  , vFullName
  , count(*) as totalCount
from [PRD_TechnoWin].[dbo].[v_Logonstats_PFB]
where vComputer not like '%-VX%'
  and vComputer not like '%-V%'
  and v_Logonstats_PFB.vComputer not like '%XDAS%'
  and v_Logonstats_PFB.vComputer not like '%XDDS%'
  and v_Logonstats_PFB.vComputer not like 'VM%'
  and v_Logonstats_PFB.vComputer not like '%TEST%'
  and v_Logonstats_PFB.vComputer not like '%FOR%'
  and v_Logonstats_PFB.vComputer not like '%GPW%%'
  and v_Logonstats_PFB.vComputer not like '%PW%'
  and v_Logonstats_PFB.vComputer not like '%DW1%'
  and v_Logonstats_PFB.vComputer not like '%GRP-PFB-32BIT%'
  and vDateTimeLogon > GETDATE() - 45
group by 
    vComputer
  , vUser
  , vFullName
order by row_number() over (partition by vUser, vcomputer order by count(*) desc)
```

or [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) with [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

```
with cte as (
    select 
        [vUser]
      , [vcomputer]
      , vFullName
      , count(*) as totalCount
      , row_number() over (partition by vUser, vcomputer order by count(*) desc)
    from [PRD_TechnoWin].[dbo].[v_Logonstats_PFB]
    where vComputer not like '%-VX%'
      and vComputer not like '%-V%'
      and v_Logonstats_PFB.vComputer not like '%XDAS%'
      and v_Logonstats_PFB.vComputer not like '%XDDS%'
      and v_Logonstats_PFB.vComputer not like 'VM%'
      and v_Logonstats_PFB.vComputer not like '%TEST%'
      and v_Logonstats_PFB.vComputer not like '%FOR%'
      and v_Logonstats_PFB.vComputer not like '%GPW%%'
      and v_Logonstats_PFB.vComputer not like '%PW%'
      and v_Logonstats_PFB.vComputer not like '%DW1%'
      and v_Logonstats_PFB.vComputer not like '%GRP-PFB-32BIT%'
      and vDateTimeLogon > GETDATE() - 45
    group by 
        vComputer
      , vUser
      , vFullName
)
select vUser, vComputer, vFullName, TotalCount
from cte
where rn = 1
```